# HTML5 Video currentTime precision in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

I've got a html5 video element and are trying to perform frame by frame stepping.
The test video I'm using is 2 frames(83ms) long and 24fps.

Playing the video works as expected, but when trying to specify the `currentTime` attribute to access frame 1 it does not work in Chrome.

Does anyone now what the precision of `currentTime` is in Chrome?

If the same operation is performed in Safari/Firefox it works as expected.

Comment: hey, have you figured out how to solve this issue?

Comment: @Ng2-Fun no, did not solve it at the time. But that was 2+ years ago so how it works in Chrome might have changed.

Comment: I am on the most current chrome version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit) and still have the same issue. If you don't solve it, then is there any alternate way to get what we want?